# How to compute unique values for a group of rows and create a column for all records using that value?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dask, dask-dataframe

I have a dask dataframe with only the 'Name' and 'Value' column similar to the table below.

[image]

How do I compute the 'Average' column? I tried groupby in dash but that just gives me a dataframe of 2 records containing the average of A and B.

Comment: Use `df['Average'] = df.groupby('Name')['Value'].transform(lambda x: x.mean())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just left join your original table with the new one on `Name`. From https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-joins.html:

```
small = small.repartition(npartitions=1)
result = big.merge(small)
```